# Why do two sleep statements chained in powershell fail?

Tags: powershell

In Win command line, you can do `cmd1 && cmd2` and `cmd2` will only be executed if `cmd1` succeeded. I think the powershell equivalent, based on other answers here, would be `(cmd1) -and (cmd2)`. However, I'm seeing weird behavior when testing it - specifically, I'm getting a fail when I should be getting true. Here's a minimal replicating example.

```
PS>(Start-Sleep 1)
PS>$?
True
PS>(Start-Sleep 1) -and (Start-Sleep 1)
False
PS>$?
True
PS>$z = (Start-Sleep 1) -and (Start-Sleep 1)
False
PS>$z
False
PS>$?
True
```

Why are the sleeps failing to chain, and why is `$z` not matching `$?`?

Comment: [1] the `$?` automatic variable contains the _execution status_ of the last operation. that has nothing whatever to do with the output of the last command. [*grin*] ///// [2] the output of `Start-Sleep` is _nothing at all_ ... and that evaluates to `false`, so the 2nd S-S will never run since the `-and` ONLY  runs the next section when the 1st section is _true_.

Comment: The `Start-Sleep` cmdlet does not return any output. Hence,  `(Start-Sleep 1)` evaluates to a `NULL` value and `[bool]$null`  evaluates to **false**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These commands are not doing what you think they're doing. Rather than executing two commands, you are asking your interpreter to evaluate two statements based on the output of the commands you have in parenthesis.

In Powershell, parenthesis are used to denote a statement that is executed first. `Start-Sleep` will return $NULL upon return because nothing was written to the buffer during execution or on return. Powershell evaluates $NULL as false, so when it comes to the `-and` check, `-and` cheats and sees that the input is $false, probably to save time.

```
(Start-Sleep -S 1) == $false
```

So what you're actually doing is saying:

```
$null -and $null
```

Which is, of course, `$false`. Because `$false` when `AND`'ed with `$false` is `$false`.

Comment: i think what actually happens with `-and` is the usual process with logical operators ... if the 1st clause is `false`, the `-and` shortcuts the remainder of the test clauses.

Answer (score 1):

Start-Sleep is $null.  But $null -and $null is $false.

```
PS C:\users\js> $a = Start-Sleep 1
PS C:\users\js> $a
PS C:\users\js> $a -eq $null
True
PS C:\users\js> $a -and $a
False
PS C:\users\js> [bool]$a
False
PS C:\users\js> $false -and $false
False
```

Short circuiting.

```
PS C:\users\js> $true -and (write-host hi)
hi
False
PS C:\users\js> $false -and (write-host hi)
False
PS C:\users\js> $true -or (write-host hi)
True
PS C:\users\js> $false -or (write-host hi)
hi
False
```

Note that in PS, -and and -or have the same precedence!